# Many images in wp-content/uploads folder that are not in Media Library

Tags: database, uploads, media-library, server, ftp

I think my database must be out of sync, or something. I checked the wp-content/uploads folder in my Bluehost File Manager and I have many more folders and files than I see in the Media Libary.

I also uploaded a file using Filezilla and copied it over to the wp-content/2023/01 folder and selected Media->Add Server to import the file, using the Add From Server plugin, but the file that I see in the Media Library is an old jpg file that's in the wp-content/2019/07 folder!

I'm a little confused at the moment, but do I have a database sync issue here?

Comment: Will you please check the path is set correctly in wp-admin dashboard under Settings -> Media. and secondly also check wp-config.php in your root of wordpress site that
define( 'UPLOADS', 'wp-content/uploads' ); is there or some else path is set. Thanks,
Vijay

Comment: I set all the image sizes to 0, if that's what you meant. I do not see any path settings other than to Organize my upload files, which I have checked. I can see that my files are organized, 

I downloaded and opened the wp-config.php file and I do not see a define statement for 'UPLOADS'

The files are uploading correctly to the right folder. That's not the problem. I can see the correct file in the File Manager.

Answer (score 0):

I sort of solved the problem by using the plugin Media Sync to add all the image files in the *wp-content/uploads* folder. I was able to see all the image files in the Media Library. I then deleted the files I was not using on my website.

I don't know what happened, but it is because I was first learning WP and tried different themes and plugins. But all of these images were left there.

I copied the FTP uploaded image to the `wp-content/uploads/2023/01` folder and imported the file using the `Media->Add Server`, but the import moved the file again to `wp-content/uploads/2019/07`! The only thing I can think of is that the database thinks this is where this file should be located and put it there. I'm not sure I can trust using the Add From Server and Media Sync plugins and the Filezilla FTP uploads.

I went back and just uploaded the image using the default method in Media->Add New and I could see that the image was located in the correct `wp-content/uploads/2023/01` folder. I left it at that.

I still had a problem in that the image was scaled down and the filename changed by appending a "-scaled" suffix. I found this link about WP automatically scaling down images and how to disable it here

```
https://make.wordpress.org/core/2019/10/09/introducing-handling-of-big-images-in-wordpress-5-3/
```

I had to install another plugin called WP Code and added the following Filter

```
add_filter( 'big_image_size_threshold', '__return_false' );
```

Once I did this, my images were not scaled down anymore.